# what does this type specification mean in a trait

Tags: rust

```
pub trait ParseTreeVisitorCompat<'input>: VisitChildren<'input, Self::Node> {
    type Node: ParserNodeType<'input>;
    type Return: Default;
```

I cant find it documented. I guess it means that the type provided for 'Return' must implement the Default trait.

Comment: These are called "associated types" and your understanding is correct. See [the Advanced Traits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html) section in the book and [Associated Types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/assoc_items/types.html) in Rust-by-example.

Comment: that section does not desribe the ':Default' part

Comment: `: Trait` is called a trait bound (Information in [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#trait-bound-syntax) and also in [the reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/trait-bounds.html)), it means the  trait has to be implemented for the type that comes before it.